# Using a recursive function ,find a program that computes the multiplication of two numbers using addition operator

Tags: c, function

Using a recurrence function ,find a program that computes the multiplication of two numbers using addition operator.

What I found is as follows:

```c
/*C program to multiply two numbers using plus operator.*/

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a,b;
    int mul,loop;

    printf("Enter first number: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Enter second number: ");
    scanf("%d",&b);

    mul=0;

    for(loop=1;loop<=b;loop++){
        mul += a;
    }

    printf("Multiplication of %d and %d is: %d\n",a,b,mul);

    return 0;
}
```

However I'm not sure if the it uses a recurrence function,can someone check that and if it does use a recursive function then show me how to do that?

Comment: Considering the only function in your code is `main` I think it's safe to say that you haven't used a recurrence function. In any case I expect you are really being asked to use a *recursive* function. A recursive function is a function which calls itself.

Comment: BTW your algorithm (repeated addition) is correct, you just have to convert the loop into a recursive function, google 'convert loop to recursion' for some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple logic should work for you:

```
int multiply(int a, int b)
{
    if(a < b)
        return multiply(b, a); // swap
    else if(b != 0)
        return (a + multiply(a, b - 1)); // recursion
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: So it does use a recursive function?

Comment: It *is* a recursive function.